# Code signing .framework failed , included framework manually

Tags: ios, code-signing, testflight

Code Signing `.framework failed.` Have included framework manually .
Tried to remove from embed binaries and included in pod file. I am getting error on pod install. This is how I have added the local framework to pod file
pod 'Framework_name',

```
:path => '../APP_ROOT_FOLDER/Resources/LibFolder/'
```

Error:

> "No podspec found for ..

Not sure whether this will resolve Code Signing failed issue

Tried to include the framework in to pod file, but pod install failed

Answer (score 3):

Got this issue resolved need to remove simulator architecture from the frameworks that we include in iOS App, on uploading it to TestFlight. Command to check if simulator architecture is present :
lipo -info

Command to remove simulator architecture from Framework:
 lipo  -remove x86_64 -output